# OpenGL 3.2: Cache compiled shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3, qt5.1

Is there any way to cache compiled shader programs using OpenGL 3.2?

I've looked at **ARB_get_program_binary** but found my driver does not support it.

I'd like to be as compatible with older cards as possible so switching to OpenGL 4 is not a good solution.

I'm working with Qt5.1 and using QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Core to access OpenGL functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides `ARB_get_program_binary`, there is no OpenGL functionality to query/cache compiled program objects.

Note that some drivers do cache program binaries by themself, like NVidia's proprietary Linux drivers which use the `~/.nv/GLCache` directory to store the cached objects. I'm not sure if other drivers do also have such a cache, but I find it quite likely.

Comment: I was afraid that might be true.